# How do I compensate the accelerometer for gravity without a gravity sensor?

Tags: accelerometer

I have an IMU with a magnetometer, accelerometer and gyroscope. How do I compensate the accelerometer for gravity to get linear_acceleration in c#?

I found this, being run each time new values are being received, but it needs a gravity sensor, which I don't seem to have

```
        float alpha = 0.8F;
        // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
        gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * accelerometer[0];
        gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * accelerometer[1];
        gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * accelerometer[2];

        // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
        linear_acceleration[0] = accelerometer[0] - gravity[0];
        linear_acceleration[1] = accelerometer[1] - gravity[1];
        linear_acceleration[2] = accelerometer[2] - gravity[2];
```

Can gravity be obtained by using the magnetometer and/or gyroscope? How?

EDIT:

According to [Gravity Compensation in Accelerometer Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252692/gravity-compensation-in-accelerometer-data) I created

```
            Matrix3D m = Matrix3D.Identity;
            Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Quaternion q1 = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(d,n,r);
            System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Quaternion q = new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Quaternion(q1.X, q1.Y, q1.Z, q1.W);
            m.Rotate(q);
            Vector3D mVtR = new Vector3D(bx, by, bz);
            m.Transform(mVtR);
            float[] gravity = new float[] { 0, 0, -9.81F };

            bx = (float)mVtR.X - gravity[0];
            by = (float)mVtR.Y - gravity[1];
            bz = (float)mVtR.Z - gravity[2];
```

With

```
                sx += bx * t * t;
                sy += by * t * t;
                sz += bz * t * t;
```

while b is acceleration, d, n and r are yaw, pitch and roll and s should be the absolute position. But it isn't. It changes even though it's steady.

Comment: isn't gravity measured with an accelerometer in the first place?

Comment: @dolan right, the example is for android in java. It is just there for the sake of argument, as a template that can easily be converted. But for this example to work, I need gravity. Can gravity be obtained by using the magnetometer and/or gyroscope?

Comment: @dolan I desire an answer for c#, putting the java tag would confuse this.

Comment: @TimoTheobald http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252692/gravity-compensation-in-accelerometer-data is this your question?

Comment: This isn't really a c# question, is it? Seems more like a math/physics question. It would be a coding question if you had the formula and wanted to write code to represent it.

Comment: @djechlin yes, that sounds good. Do you have an implementation for that?