# Major change of distance values after double integration even though device remains steady

Tags: c#, xna, accelerometer, quaternions, ms-media-foundation

I have an IMU with a magnetometer, accelerometer and gyroscope. According to [Gravity Compensation in Accelerometer Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252692/gravity-compensation-in-accelerometer-data) I created

```
void newValues()
{    
  //get values
  ...
  stopwatch.Stop();
  t = (float)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
  stopwatch.Restart();
  Matrix3D m = Matrix3D.Identity;
  Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Quaternion q1 = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(d,n,r);
  System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Quaternion q = new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Quaternion(q1.X, q1.Y, q1.Z, q1.W);
  m.Rotate(q);
  Vector3D mVtR = new Vector3D(bx, by, bz);
  m.Transform(mVtR);
  float[] gravity = new float[] { 0, 0, -9.81F };

  bx = (float)mVtR.X - gravity[0];
  by = (float)mVtR.Y - gravity[1];
  bz = (float)mVtR.Z - gravity[2];

  sx += bx * t * t;
  sy += by * t * t;
  sz += bz * t * t;
}
```

while `b` is `acceleration`, `d`, `n` and `r` are `yaw`, `pitch` and `roll` and `s` should be the `absolute position`. `t` is the time between new values come in. But the absolute position `s` significantly changes even though the imu is steady. Why is that?

Comment: one possible factor contributing to your problem could be that your gravity vector assumes a Z-up world system but an XNA identity matrix and an XNA quaternion both utilize a Y-up world system.

Comment: @SteveH so you suggest `float[] gravity = new float[] { 0, 0, 9.81F };` ?