# how to remove gravity from real accelaration 3-axis?

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, gravity, nrf51, mpu

I wanted to remove gravity from my 3-axis data, Please help me fixing it.

```
            mpu9250_read_accel(&AccValue);
            AX =    ((AccValue.x *9800)/(16384));
            AY =    ((AccValue.y *9800)/(16384));
            AZ =    ((AccValue.z *9800)/(16384));
```

Comment: My guess is to remove `* 9800` part (Earth's gravitation acceleration is 9.8m/s)

Comment: You mean to try this below                                        
            mpu9250_read_accel(&AccValue);
            AX =    ((AccValue.x )/(16384));
            AY =    ((AccValue.y )/(16384));
            AZ =    ((AccValue.z )/(16384));

Comment: Yep, and you can probably do away without the `(` and `)`. Like so: `AX = AccValue.x / 16384;`

Comment: Nope, We are getting the same kind of value.

Comment: That's a bummer... Well, I saw a few similar questions here, some say MPUs are not accurate to do gravity compensation. Others refer to basic algorithms, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252692/gravity-compensation-in-accelerometer-data

Comment: Hello Sir,                                                                                                 
Help me, How to calculate quaternion values using Accelerometer, magnotometer, Gyrometer??

Comment: That's a really good question. I wish I could, but this is way too out of my league. Most of the physics I ever did is in-game, not real world. I believe you can open another question, or search SO. Good luck!